# React Native NavigatorExperimental - Combine AnimatedView with CardStack

Tags: react-native, navigator

i 've a NavigationAnimatedView which rendering a ListView with pushed DetailsView.

In the NavigationHeader, on the rightComponent, i have a button and i want to display a view with NavigationCardStack from bottomToTop. How can i combine the two modes of navigation ?

Like the filters button on the F8 app on the home screen.

i don't understand how with a dispatch action (navigatePush ?) on the FiltersButton, i can't switch with a navigationCardStack to display a FilterViews from BottomToTop.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide props to NavigationCard when you render it:

```
_renderScene(props) {
  return (
    <NavigationCard
      style={NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.forVertical(props)}
      ...
```

Sorry that part isn't documented very well right now!